# move DOM element position dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm generating spans dynamically and placing their location as such:

```
        $('#myObstacles').append("<span id=\"" +  test + randX + "\">" + items[randObj] + "</span>");
        document.getElementById("test"+randX).style.position="absolute";
        document.getElementById("test"+randX).style.left=randX;
        document.getElementById("test"+randX).style.top=randY;
```

Then I have `setInterval()` function that should move these DOM spans every so often by calling `moveSpans()`:

```
    function moveSpans() {
        $("#myObstacles span").each(function (index, val) {
            val.style.top-=10;
        });
    }
```

For some reason, the appended DOM spans to `#myObstacles` don't change position.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "function(index, val)" the "val" is a jQuery object, try:

```
function moveSpans() {
    $("#myObstacles span").each(function (index, val) {
        $(val).css({top: -10});
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not setting the `css top` to 10 px, I want to incrementally move it towards the top by 10px. So something like `.css({top-=10})`?

Answer (score 1):

As Wlises said, you need to stick with the jQuery methods or the core JavaScript methods; if you're using a jQuery object (which is returned in callback functions as `val` like in the one above), stick with the jQuery method `.css()`.

Therefore:

- **GOOD**: `val.css("top","-=10")`
- **BAD**: `val.style.top -= 10` (This is a native JavaScript property, but for jQuery objects, there is NO `style` property. There is only the `.css()` accessor/mutator method.)

Since you are trying to decrement `top` by 10px, it is acceptable to use: `val.css("top","-=10")`

Here's an explanation straight from the jQuery documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.6, `.css()` accepts relative values similar to `.animate()`. Relative values are a string starting with `+=` or `-=` to increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's padding-left was 10px, `.css( "padding-left", "+=15" )` would result in a total padding-left of 25px.

Comment: Thank you, but `val.css("top","-=10");` in the `$.each` doesn't work, giving error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLSpanElement> has no method 'css'` in console

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
function moveSpans() {
    $("#myObstacles span").each(function (index, val) {
        var $el = $(val)
        $el.css({top: $el.css("top")-10});
    });
}
```